# Distinct value from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union

I have 4 tables which contains "ID"  and 1 table which contains "ID" & "TEAM". All "ID"'s  from the first four tables is also stored in the fifth table with a "TEAM"-name attached to it. The tables contains more data than id but its not relevant.

I want to select "ID" from the 4 tables WHERE "TEAM" is a chosen one from me. I want them all in the same array to use in mysql_fetch_array to output rows.

I've tried a lot of things but cant work it out how to get correct output. I need a distinct output so multiples shall not be written out. Appreciate all help!

```
TABLE1

ID : 50454
ID : 50454
ID : 50454
ID : 30545


TABLE2

ID : 20876
ID : 10678
ID : 10678
ID : 10678


TABLE3

ID : 60321
ID : 90123


TABLE4

ID : 32505
ID : 32505
ID : 32505
ID : 32151


TABLE5

ID : 32505        TEAM : ALFA
ID : 32151        TEAM : ALFA
ID : 90123        TEAM : ALFA
ID : 60321        TEAM : ALFA
ID : 50454        TEAM : BETA
ID : 30545        TEAM : BETA
ID : 20876        TEAM : BETA
ID : 10678        TEAM : BETA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if you need all Id's form ALFA team:

```
select DISTINCT ID

FROM
(
select Id from Table1 JOIN Table5 on Table1.ID=Table5.Id WHERE Table5.Team='ALFA'
union all
select Id from Table2 JOIN Table5 on Table2.ID=Table5.Id WHERE Table5.Team='ALFA'
union all
select Id from Table3 JOIN Table5 on Table3.ID=Table5.Id WHERE Table5.Team='ALFA'
union all
select Id from Table4 JOIN Table5 on Table4.ID=Table5.Id WHERE Table5.Team='ALFA'
) T1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch all rows and store your results into an array then use

`array_unique()`

function to get distinct results

Comment: Yes, but i need the output to be affected by "TEAM" in TABLE5. BUt now it just mess things up. @M2sh

Comment: @PeterP oh yes, your last table have additional column that called Team? i think you can fetch all rows without any additional column like Team , after that select Team data for unique ids from Table5.